# Why am I billed for hourly AWS workspace when it's stopped?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I configured two hourly performance AWS workspaces about 2 months ago. The fee for each is 9.75/mo + .47/hour.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I used each maybe only 3 hours each so I would expect a bill of about $22.32 ((9.75 x 2) + (.47 x 6))but my bill was over $70 (which equals about 100 hours). I reached out to support and this is what they concluded:

> As per checking with the Service Team, they have advised that WorkSpaces are billed on a monthly basis, and you pay only for the WorkSpaces you launch that allow end-users to access the documents, applications and resources they need with the device of their choice, including laptops, iPad, Kindle Fire, or Android tablets. So even if the service is on a stop mode, as long as users keep on accessing to the documents, desktops or even domains you have the WorkSpace associated to, will incur in charges.

I am the only user and I didn't interact with the stopped workspaces. I don't have any other AWS services interacting with these workspaces. I don't even understand how users could access "documents, desktops or even domains you have the WorkSpace associated to" if the workspace is stopped.

I have trouble drilling down to the necessary level of detail using the AWS billing dashboard - so I just feel like I have a blindspot here. Why am I getting billed so much? How can I get more details about these Workspace charges?

Comment: Would question it again. Ask for the documents it is associated with. Let them explain what has to be changed. Maybe it will not get your money back, but this behavior does not seem to me to be clear from their documentation. And I considered to run a similar setup, but now I will wait until I see an explanation to this case.

Comment: Their description does not make sense. There is no "document" concept for WorkSpaces. I think they are saying "It is on Auto-Stop, but you're still using it". I would also suggest you manually stop the WorkSpaces in future. See: [Manage the WorkSpace running mode - Amazon WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/running-mode.html)

Comment: Worth a shot @petrch. I just submitted a follow-up requesting more details. I'll update this question if I get more info from support.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Support actually called me. They were a big help in demystifying the charges. The short answer is that I'm a dummy. But I wanted to provide an explanation, info and links for others who want to get more details about their own usage and bill.

AWS has a few other helpful ways to get more info. The first was the bill itself (From your [billing home page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home) click on 'Bills' in the top left). The first thing I learned was that (1) my bill was $50 not $70. I might have combined my Jan and Feb bill or thought their 'estimate' was the bill. Either way - my baseline was wrong. (2) I also had an RDS instance running which accounted for $16. (3) Finally I could see an exact breakdown of workspace charges. There was the base monthly charge of 9.75. Then there was the .47 hourly charge for 22 hours which accounted for 10.34. The charges we're adding up - but the hours seemed too high.

[image]

This was great but I asked if there was a way to see *when* I used those 22 hours because that was still more than I had recorded myself. He directed me to the [cost explorer](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/costexplorer). On the cost explorer specifically there was a histogram with a button on the top right to "View in Cost Explorer".

[image]

There I was able to view how much I was billed per day. Using the group by options on the top we grouped by 'Service' to see this

[image]

This showed that nearly all of those hours were on one day. I think that's when I set things up and might not have had AutoStop toggled. So just make sure you have your workspace configured for AutoStop if that's best for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for detailing your experience.

Mine was also a bit confusing.  I needed to build an image which included a bundle of apps my business uses.  I started with a template and then took an image of that, then bundled the imagage with resources and built 2 workspaces for my two office employees.

I then realized that there was a wrong config in the deployed workspaces so I deleted the workspace, fixed the image, and then redeployed the workspaces with the correct config.

I was billed the fixed portion ($13) for each one of those workspaces that lived for about 15 minutes before I deleted them. I had a one day workspace bill for about $65 (we're a very small business so that's a bummer)  Live and learn.